# Example: How To Turn On LED2 On STM32 In Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32, keil

Hey was just wondering if someone could post an example of how to use GPIO_MODR, AHB1ENR and GPIO_BSSR for setting up an LED on an STM32 board in assembly, any help is greatly appreciated; thanks!

Comment: the stm32 is too generic the various stm32 chips dont have the same gpio peripherals, what chip specifically, what did you try?  which part do you not understand the assembly language or how to use the peripheral? what does your boot code/program look like thus far?

Comment: then if you are asking about an led then how is it wired to the chip?  what pin/port, etc?

Comment: what part of the documentation do you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Compile your C code. See how it is done in the compiled code (port GPIOA, pin 10):

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define __IO volatile

typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t MODER;    /*!< GPIO port mode register,               Address offset: 0x00      */
  __IO uint32_t OTYPER;   /*!< GPIO port output type register,        Address offset: 0x04      */
  __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;  /*!< GPIO port output speed register,       Address offset: 0x08      */
  __IO uint32_t PUPDR;    /*!< GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register,  Address offset: 0x0C      */
  __IO uint32_t IDR;      /*!< GPIO port input data register,         Address offset: 0x10      */
  __IO uint32_t ODR;      /*!< GPIO port output data register,        Address offset: 0x14      */
  __IO uint32_t BSRR;     /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset,               Address offset: 0x18      */
  __IO uint32_t LCKR;     /*!< GPIO port configuration lock register, Address offset: 0x1C      */
  __IO uint32_t AFR[2];   /*!< GPIO alternate function registers,     Address offset: 0x20-0x24 */
} GPIO_TypeDef;

#define PERIPH_BASE               (0x40000000UL) /*!< Base address of : AHB/APB Peripherals                                                   */
#define D3_AHB1PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x18020000UL)
#define GPIOA_BASE            (D3_AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0000UL)
#define GPIOA               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)

void foo()
{
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~(0b11 << (10 * 2));
    GPIOA -> MODER |= 1 << (10 * 2);
    while(1)
    {
        GPIOA -> BSRR = 1 << 10;
        GPIOA -> BSRR = 1 << (10 + 16);
    }
}
```

---

```
foo:
        ldr     r3, .L3
        mov     r1, #1024
        ldr     r2, [r3]
        bic     r2, r2, #3145728
        str     r2, [r3]
        ldr     r2, [r3]
        orr     r2, r2, #1048576
        str     r2, [r3]
        mov     r2, #67108864
.L2:
        str     r1, [r3, #24]
        str     r2, [r3, #24]
        b       .L2
.L3:
        .word   1476526080
```

Comment: you are assuming a specific STM32 chip how did you determine which one the OP is using?

Comment: blinking that fast will generally not glow the led enough to be visible.

Comment: Based on timing and subject matter this seems like it another user that has a second username to continue a thread of read the manual for me questions.

Comment: @old_timer chip model is not important. #defines are not important. The resulting code will be very similar. It shows the idea. No one sane will write assembler (except some system routines maybe). l

Comment: I would think it is obvious to the most casual observer why the OP is writing assembler: it is an assignment for a course.

Comment: I sometimes start with asm examples due to the nature of finding a working assembler vs a working cross compiler.  it is significantly easier to come across a working compiler now so an asm example is not as important.

Comment: most of your code will change depending on the specific chip so is this helpful or creates several more questions

Comment: you also assumed the architecture, this asm code is not portable across stm32 products, you could have built it in a portable way instead of creating more problems having to be debugged.

Comment: and I am guessing you used gcc instead of kiel? assembly language is defined by the toolchain not the target.

Comment: @old_timer I have no clue what are you talking about.

Comment: which part, you generated armv7-m code which is only compatible with some stm32s or that assembly language varies by assembler and is not universal for a target and this appears to be gas not kiel?  or that the various stms that use this gpio ip dont use the same addresses in the register space?  or the user may be using a different port and pin?

Comment: I am happy to see that it isnt unified syntax, I hate the unified syntax.

Comment: @old_timer *`"you generated armv7-m code which is only compatible with some stm32"`*. Which stm32s are not compatible with generated code? Examples of the live parts please. If the GPIO address is different it is rather obvious for any (even beginner) programmer what has to be changed.

Comment: @old_timer  `I hate the unified syntax` - it is not my problem

Comment: mov     r1, #1024 and almost everything else with a constant is an armv7-m thumb2 extension not armv6-m compatible if you had built for armv6-m then it would be compatible across all of the STM32s

Comment: assume some assemblers will only accept unified syntax, it is your problem.  you didnt appear to generate assembly for kiel/arm but for gnu so you need to use the proper assembly language syntax to provide an assembly language example.  you created a nightmare for a beginner not a solution.

Comment: @old_timer so the programmer will change the syntax for its favourite assembler. It does not change the general idea.

Comment: could have covered the I dont know assembly language as well as the I dont know how to use the registers in a way that the answer provides a high percentage chance of success.  but no explication on how the regsters are used and output assembly that has a small percentage chance of working, and no indication how to use the tools to generate the assembly, etc.